# Floating point number addition

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

I need to add two decimal floating point numbers by hand. I know I have to round after each intermediate calculation, but the decimal digit precision is not specified. All I know is that the numbers are stored in the IEEE 754 half precision format. How can I do the rounding without knowing the precision?

Comment: Are you sure you mean “decimal”? “half-precision” means 16-bit wide in this context, and there is no “decimal16” IEEE 754 format. There is a “binary16” format: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format . If you meant that you wish to add numbers in this format, write them down in binary, it will help. Thinking of these numbers in terms of “decimal digit precision” only leads to confusion.

Comment: @PascalCuoq, by "decimal", I meant that the problem is stated in decimal. For example, calculate (4.874533 x 10^(-1) + 1.564 x 10^3) + 1.4655 x 10^(-1). So, I can either do the calculations in decimal or I can convert to binary as you suggested. In any case, I need to know the precision to do the rounding, right?

Comment: You need to know the **binary** precision. It's on the page I linked to: 10 explicit bits, and an implicit leading `1` for normal numbers. Converting between decimal and binary is much, much harder than adding two floating-point numbers, so it is surprising that an exercise purported to be about floating-point addition would involve conversion. Anyway, a good introduction to the general problem of converting to and from decimal is Rick Regan's “Exploring Binary” blog.

Comment: Or, convert your decimal representations to single-precision (32-bit) with the C function `strtof()`, and find and apply a function to convert from binary32 to binary16. There are plenty of these floating on the internet. This assumes the absence of double-rounding issues in the numbers you have to work with.

Comment: Yes. Technically, was I was saying was that you should do all the computations in binary, but if you insist on doing them in decimal, you must compute exact results for each decimal computation (in order to avoid the double-rounding problem) and then round the result of the computation to the nearest representable binary16 number. You cannot round the decimal computation to any number of “approximative number of significant decimal digits” because however small the rounding, it can make the difference between a value below a midpoint—that should be rounded down— and a value above a midpoint—…